# Dynamically load subtitles into video

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, html5-video, blob

Here is the situation: The server receives the **srt** file stream. The server converts the stream into **vtt** format. The resulting stream is then buffered into a buffer which is then sent to client through a io.socket.

Here is the **server code**:

```
self.expressApp.post("/upload", function (req, res) {
var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
        busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
            var subchunks = [],
                sub = file.pipe(srt2vtt());
            sub.on('data',function(buffer){
                subchunks.push(buffer);
            });
            sub.on('end',function(){
                var buffer = Buffer.concat(subchunks);
                socket.emit('Subtitles',buffer);
            });
        });
        busboy.on('finish', function() {
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Connection': 'close' });
            res.end();
        });
        return req.pipe(busboy);
});
```

Here is the **client code**:

```
var subobj = new Blob([new Uint8Array(payload)],{type: "text/vtt"}),
    url = (URL || webkitURL).createObjectURL(subobj),
    track = document.createElement("track");                
    track.kind = "captions";
    track.label = "English";
    track.srclang = "en";
    track.src = url;
    track.addEventListener("load", function() {
        this.mode = "showing";
        videoElement.textTracks[0].mode = "showing";
    });
    videoElement.append(track);
```

Why this is not working. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If anyone is interested in client-only usage with local files, try what I made. https://github.com/anemochore/add-sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution.

**What was I doing wrong?**

I was sending the vtt stream as binary array rather than plan text string.

**Server-side Code:**

```
self.expressApp.post("/upload", function (req, res) {
        var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
        busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
            var subchunks = "",
                sub = file.pipe(srt2vtt());
            sub.on('data',function(buffer){
                subchunks += buffer.toString('utf8');
            });
            sub.on('end',function(){
                socket.emit('Subtitles',subchunks);
            });
        });
        busboy.on('finish', function() {
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Connection': 'close' });
            res.end();
        });
        return req.pipe(busboy);
});
```

**Client-side Code:**

```
var subobj = new Blob([new Uint8Array(payload)],{type: "text/vtt"}),
    url = (URL || webkitURL).createObjectURL(subobj),
    track = document.createElement("track");                
track.kind = "captions";
track.label = "English";
track.srclang = "en";
track.src = url;
videoElement.append(track);
track.mode = "showing";
videoElement.textTracks[0].mode = "showing";
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm using plyr, there are some bug for dashjs captions, so i created a blob of that webvtt and append that on video container, here is my code

```
 fetch("url")
.then(response => response.text())
.then(result => {
    var blob = new Blob([result], {
        type: "text/vtt"
    });
    const track = document.createElement('track');
    Object.assign(track, {
        label: 'language',
        default: true,
        src: window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    });
    video.appendChild(track);
})
.catch(error => console.log('error', error));`
```